# "If I (went/will go) to the past with a time machine"

Tags: difference, tense, sentence-choice

Should I say "I went to the past" because a word referring to action in the past have to be in past tense? But I hear some people say "I will go to the past.".

So which is correct?

Comment: In casea of time travel, normal sequence of tenses is temporarily suspended.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand

Comment: Oh I understand the tense is suspended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we all know, it's impossible to go to the past :-)

So then both of your sentences are proper grammar, just they mean different things.

- "I went to the past" means that in the past you went to the past.
- "I will go to the past" means that in the future you will go back to the past.

Of course it's impossible to do so, but maybe in movies and cartoons you can see these sentences being mentioned.

Comment: Or, following the example of your heading, "If I were to go to the past..." (using the subjunctive for a hypothetical situation).